# Using canonical definitions, can a polynomial have non-integer degree less than 1? Integer degree less than zero?

Tags: polynomials, definition

Like all common terms in mathematics, "polynomial" has very slightly different definitions depending upon your reference text; but they differ only in superfluous ways.

Are there any canonical/popular definitions polynomial which allow them to have degree less than 1?

For example, is $\frac{1}{x} = x^{-1}$ a polynomial on $x$?

What about non-integer degrees? Is $\sqrt{x} = x^{0.5}$ a polynomial on $x$?

Comment: Linear combinations of fractional powers can be called fractional polynomials. For negative powers, I don't know.

Comment: [Laurent polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_polynomial) are allowed to have negative powers of the indeterminate.